# My fonts on hompage are working correct, on the other pages not

Tags: css

I have a problem i am trying to solve it for a week or so.. On my front page my font-family is Montserrat. This is how i want to be. On every other pages (no matter what i did) my font is other (when checking online they say it is Montserrat but it is not)

https://tricourilemele.ro

I think something is blocking this font on every other page but homepage.

Could someone take a look. I would appreciate it..
It gets me out of my mind.

Thank you so much!

Marius

Comment: Hi it would be great if you could share what you have done in `CSS` for adding `font-family` .It will be more helpful.

Comment: Seems like you did not include fonts from Google on the other pages, looking at network tab on Chrome DevTools

Comment: In my wordpress Dashboard i checked on Apparence >> Themes - Storefront - Customize - Typography - Heading font - Montserrat       and in Custom CSS    this          .woocommerce ul.products li.product .woocommerce-loop-product__title{
   font-family: Montserrat;
}

Comment: What does it means  ""did not include fonts from Google on the other pages""

Comment: I added in my header "<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">     no change

Comment: Solved. Yes, the answer is that i have a plugin who is blocking  fonts from Google on the other pages.. Thank you!